# my $to variable contains email addresses but i want it one by one in mail function that it gets first email and send it ,then move on second address

Tags: php, email

> ```
> $to="example@.com,example@.com"; // i want this email addresses one by one in $tto in mail function
> $contacts = array("$to");
> foreach($contacts as $contact) 
> {
> $tto = $contact;
> $subject="hey";
> $body="Test";
> $header="example@.com";
> if(mail($tto,$subject,$body,$header))
>   {
>       echo "SEND";
>   }}
>
> ?>
> ```
>
> my $to variable contains email addresses but i want it one by one in
>   mail function that it gets first email and send it ,then move on
>   second address, i have tried this code but this is not working

Comment: Take a look at the `explode()` function... http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

to change/split a string into an array we can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

in case they are always in comma-separated form:

```
$to = "example@domain.com,example2@domain.com";
$contacts = explode(",", $to);
array_walk($contacts, 'trim');

// The rest of your code ... (starting from 'foreach')
```

Comment: could you please guide me that how can i add attachment bcc and cc in mail function

Comment: @umairkhan, It's inappropriate to move the goal post like that. You should take this answer as a response the original question. Personally, I think this is the best/only solution for this problem and you should accept this answer. Your follow up question isn't related to this problem and should be asked in a different question - though it sounds poor quality already and you should just read the documentation instead.